# I need to interact with web logic server for response using Ajax in angularjs?

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs

I am actually working with webRTC technology .So, in order to maintain my front end effectively i am interested moving to angularjs.

i need to work with web logic server by using ajax and angularjs as front end.
and java is for my back end purpose  . If it is possible please suggest me how to?

thank you

Comment: Please try to include examples of what you have tried, and what specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Short question, short answer:

Use angular's [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).